# Custom widget select options needs to stay selected after save

Tags: customization, widgets, options, select

I am working on a custom widget that includes a select options drop-down list of pages.  When I select a page and save, the selected option does not stay selected.  However, if I refresh the widgets page, the selected option (page) does show as selected.

```
class slideshow_widget extends WP_Widget {
// Main constructor
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(
        'slideshow_widget',
        __( 'Slideshow', 'text_domain' ),
        array(
            'customize_selective_refresh' => true,
        )
    );
}
// The widget form (for the backend )
public function form( $instance ) {
    // Set widget defaults
    $defaults = array(
        'title'    => '',
        'text'     => '',
        'textarea' => '',
        'select_page'   => '',
    );
    $links = array();
    $pages = get_pages();
    foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
        $links[$page->ID] = array(
            'title' => $page->post_title,
            'url'   => get_permalink( $page->ID )
        );
    }
    // Parse current settings with defaults
    extract( wp_parse_args( ( array ) $instance, $defaults ) ); ?>

    <?php // Widget Title ?>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Widget Title:', 'text_domain' ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'title' ) ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <?php // Text Field ?>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'text' ) ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Slide Heading:', 'text_domain' ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'text' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'text' ) ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $text ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <?php // Textarea Field ?>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'textarea' ) ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Slide Text:', 'text_domain' ); ?></label>
        <textarea class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'textarea' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'textarea' ) ); ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $textarea ); ?></textarea>
    </p>
    <?php // Dropdown ?>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'select_page' ) ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Target Page:', 'text_domain' ); ?></label>
        <select class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'select_page' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'select_page' ) ); ?>" >
            <?php foreach ( $links as $id => $link ): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $link['url'] ?>" <?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'select_page' ) == $link['url'] ? 'selected' : ''; ?> >
                    <?php echo $link['title'] ?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </select>
    </p>
<?php }
// Update widget settings
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = $old_instance;
    $instance['title']    = isset( $new_instance['title'] ) ? wp_strip_all_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
    $instance['text']     = isset( $new_instance['text'] ) ? wp_strip_all_tags( $new_instance['text'] ) : '';
    $instance['textarea'] = isset( $new_instance['textarea'] ) ? wp_kses_post( $new_instance['textarea'] ) : '';
    $instance['select_page']   = isset( $new_instance['select_page'] ) ? wp_strip_all_tags( $new_instance['select_page'] ) : '';
    return $instance;
}

// Display the widget
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    extract( $args );
    // Check the widget options
    $title    = isset( $instance['title'] ) ? apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] ) : '';
    $text     = isset( $instance['text'] ) ? $instance['text'] : '';
    $textarea = isset( $instance['textarea'] ) ?$instance['textarea'] : '';
    $select_page   = isset( $instance['select_page'] ) ? $instance['select_page'] : '';
    // WordPress core before_widget hook (always include )
    echo $before_widget;
    // Display the widget
    echo '<div class="widget-text wp_widget_plugin_box">';
        // Display widget title if defined
        if ( $title ) {
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
        }
        // Display text field
        if ( $text ) {
            echo '<p>' . $text . '</p>';
        }
        // Display textarea field
        if ( $textarea ) {
            echo '<p>' . $textarea . '</p>';
        }
        // Display selected page field
        if ( $select_page ) {
    $page_url =  parse_url($select_page, PHP_URL_PATH);
            echo '<p>' . $page_url . '</p>';
        }
    echo '</div>';
    // WordPress core after_widget hook (always include )
    echo $after_widget;
}}
```

I was able to fix...

Replaced:

```
<?php foreach ( $links as $id => $link ): ?>
<option value="<?php echo $link['url'] ?>" <?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'select_page' ) == $link['url'] ? 'selected' : ''; ?> >
    <?php echo $link['title'] ?>
</option><?php endforeach ?>
```

With:

```
<?php foreach ( $links as $id => $link ) { echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $link['url'] ) . '" id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '" '. selected( $select_page, $link['url'], false ) . '>'. $link['title'] . '</option>';} ?>
```